# Eclipse: How to install Java programming support after installing Eclipse Javascript version

Tags: eclipse

How does one install basic the basic Java programming environment AFTER having installed the specific Eclipse for Javascript . . . or should I scrap it and intall Eclipse for Java THEN install the Javascript plug-in?

Answer (score 1):

You may use Help->Install new software. There you can put http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo or http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7 and choose everything you need. At least it worked when I've installed basic eclipse for java SE first, and then, using this window, upgrade it for usage of java EE.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the same workspace and keep your preference, you should able to switch different version without much problem.

You can export your preference by File > Export.